# Possible to use ViewPager without needing to use AppCompat theme?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design, android-appcompat

I'm working on an app that makes extensive use of ViewPagers.  If you use a ViewPager, your Activity must extend AppCompatActivity. This means you have to use a theme for the activity that inherits from "Theme.AppCompat".  This means using the Material Design framework can be very difficult and manual. For example, you can't specify transition animations in XML.

Is anybody aware of any way of using ViewPager without being forced to develop your whole app using a Holo approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to extend `AppCompatActivity` in order to use `ViewPager`, you can use it inside normal `Activity` too, [here's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) an example. `ViewPager` is part of the support library v4 package. You can add dependency on support library v4 by adding following lines to your build.gradle file.

```
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0"
```